# div inside another div

Tags: asp.net, html

I am trying to create a div inside another div in the asp.net code behind however the inside div is not shown, only the one outside is. I tried the inner div alone and its worked and tried the outer div alone too which worked as well.

```
    public System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
    public System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl pic = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("IMG");

    public ResultsDiv()
    {
        this.div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "60px");
        this.div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "300px");
        this.div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginBottom, "40px");
        this.div.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='#4099FF'");
        this.div.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='silver'");
        this.div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "silver");

        this.tweet.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "60px");
        this.tweet.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "60px");
        this.tweet.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "red");
        this.tweet.Style["float"] = "left";

        div.Controls.Add(this.tweet);
```

Comment: I can't see anywhere in that code where you try to create a `<div />` inside another `<div />`.

Comment: I'm not seeing where your second `DIV` is, also what is `tweet`

Comment: tweet is of type <div>. "div" is too of type <div>. hence div.Controls.Add(this.tweet);
puts the tweet <div> inside the div <div>

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to do this in the server side ? To create a simple div inside another div,making a server round trip ?  I would do it in my client side using javascript if possible.

If you want to have some data from your server you may use ajax to load that too.

Here is a javascript sample.
HTML

```
<div id="div1" ></div>
<br/><input id="btn1" type="button" value="Add div" />
```

Javascript

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){    
    $("#div1").append("<div class='div2'> Here is my content !</div>");

});
```

Jsfiddle sample : http://jsfiddle.net/7Rzdb/4/

Comment: yes it is much simpler that way but it MUST be serverside.the div tags must be created on the fly, and the number of them depends on a certain process result